# Binary search on the vector of structs

Tags: c++, vector, struct, binary-tree

I have a vector of structs that contains struct with this architecture

```
struct Main{

   int mainID;
   string mainDIV;
   string mainNAME;

}
```

is it possible to use binary search on struct? I know its easy to use on value using

```
binary_search( vector.begin() , vector.end() , 5 )
```

But is there a way how to pass callback or something to actually find attribute of struct? I fail to find anything related to thi topic.

Comment: 2nd method: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search

Comment: I dont know if i am stupid. But the link didnt help at all.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible. The `value` that [`std::binary_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) takes is only meaningful when compared to the elements of the container. In the simple case (if `Main` supports `operator<` somewhere), you would provide an element of type `Main` as the value:

```
// check if this specific Main exists
bool yes = std::binary_search(v.begin(), v.end(), Main{0, "some", "strings"});

// does exactly the same thing as above
bool yes = std::binary_search(v.begin(), v.end(), Main{0, "some", "strings"}
    , std::less<Main>{});
```

If it doesn't support `operator<` (or your container is ordered by something else, e.g. `mainID`), then you will have to provide a comparator yourself that the algorithm will use:

```
// check if there is a Main with mainID 5
bool yes = std::binary_search(v.begin(), v.end(), 5,
    [](const Main& element, const int value) {
        return element.mainID < value;
    });
```

Comment: Is it possible to omit string and check just for the integer? Wont this find exactly struct with same int and strings ?

Answer (score 4):

You have to provide information to `binary_search()` to tell it how to compare your objects.  The two most common ways, are to either add an `operator<()` to the `struct` if that is possible, or provide a helper function that can compare two `struct`s.

The first form would look something like this:

```
struct Main {
  int mainID ;
  string mainDIV ;
  string mainNAME ;
  bool operator<(const Main & other) const
  {
    return mainID < other.mainID ;
  }
}
```

This will only compare on on `mainID`, but you can expand it from there.

Also, this only teaches the compiler how to compare two `struct Main`, while @Barry's answer above will match an int and a `struct Main`.  But lets keep going with this answer.

Now to find the record for `5`, we have to make it into a `struct Main`:

```
struct Main search_key = { 5 } ;
bool yes = std::binary_search( v.begin(), v.end(), search_key ) ;
```

Now, this isn't very elegant, and besides if you have a constructor for `struct Main` ( and haven't put it in your example ), this won't even work.  So we add another constructor just for `int`.

```
struct Main
{
    Main(int id, const string & a_div, const string & a_name ) : id(id), div(a_div), name(a_name) { }
    Main(int id) : id(id) { }
    int id ;
    string div, name ;

    bool operator<(const Main &o) const { return id < o.id ; }
} ;
```

Now we can do a slightly shorter form:

```
bool has_3 = std::binary_search( v.begin(), v.end(), Main( 3) ) ;
```

Historical note:  Bjarne has been trying for quite some time to get default comparison operators into the standard, but not everyone was excited about it at the standards meetings.  I though there was some progress on it at the last meeting and so it may eventually appear when C++17 is a thing.

Comment: You can add some code to compare the other components in Main if there is a match on mainID.

Comment: I'm recently trying to figure out the same problem i declared operator in my structure. But how do i call the binary search ? Could your provide more code please with the binary_search function?

Comment: this throw this error C:\Users\Matej\Desktop\PA2\Progtest\2_trieda\main.cpp|107|error: could not convert '{invID}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to Main'|